# PHP save form data to file

Tags: php

I am trying to save form data to a file, this is what I have so far:

```
if(isset($_POST['connect'])) {
    $host = "$dbuser=" . $_POST["host"];
    $root = $_POST["root"];
    $pass = $_POST["pass"];
}
```

I'm trying to write the form data to a file with the variable `$dbhost="Formdata";`
and I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\dev\admin2.0\install\index.php on line 55`
```

Comment: The syntax error has nothing to do with the code that you posted.  Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = '$dbhost="' . $_POST["host"] . '"';
echo $host;
```

Try this.  You don't need to echo unless you are attempting to print to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you trying to accomplish, but if you want to write some data to a file (for example), you could try something like this:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['connect'])) {
    file_put_contents("file.txt", "$dbuser={$_POST["host"]}");
  }
```

Also keep in mind that notation:

```
 "$dbuser="
```

will expand variable in place (1), if a variable `$dbuser` exists, because you are using double quotes.
With single quotes you will need string concatenation operator `.` like this:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['connect'])) {
    file_put_contents("file.txt", '$dbuser=' . $_POST["host"]);
  }
```

But, if this all about plain debug, maybe `print_r($_POST);` will be sufficient?

Hope this helps!

[PHP Reference: Strings (please read section "Variable parsing").](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing)

Comment: The `"$dbuser={$_POST["host"]}"` is invalid because double quotes within double quotes must be escaped: `"$dbuser={$_POST[\"host\"]}"`

Comment: Are you sure about that dear Anonymous? http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php